# Change Anchor Target based on Text using JavaScript (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I have c# code which generates Anchor tags on fly. I wanted to change some of anchor tag target based on its text.

For example dynamic code generated HTML like below

```
<a target='_blank' class=txt href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">THE BEST SITE</a>
```

I wanted to change its target if text equals THE BEST SITE

Note: I have no jQuery files included in asp.net project.

So far I have tried including this script just to get the text, but it is not even displaying the alert

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".txt").click(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: You have no jQuery but you're trying jQuery?

Comment: Can we use jQuery or not? Your example has jQuery....

Comment: I just realized that the code I am using is jQuery. Took out the code from my script.

Comment: Show us more of your html structure, so we can propose a code that navigates through your DOM.

Comment: Do you want it to change on load or on click?

Comment: Have you tried adding jQuery to the project?  Multiple ways to do this, and it largely compresses the code that you would have to right.  If not, me/someone can generate a non-jQuery solution, but it's usually easier to use a library to get past the tons of boilerplate.

Comment: @Aweary want to change it onLoad

Comment: @angus_thermopylae I cannot add jQuery at this time.

Comment: Ok.  Aweary is already on the case for that.  Looking good so far.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that your tag is malformatted. Most browsers will correct it for you, but it might lead to some odd behavior. It should look like this: `<a target="_blank" class="txt" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">THE BEST SITE</a>`, with double-quotes around each attribute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function that checks if an element's innerText is equal to a specific phrase. If it is, it sets the target attribute specific to that phrase.

```
 function changeTarget(elem, phrase){
       if(elem.innerText === phrase){
         elem.target = phrase;
       }
    }
```

Depending on your DOM, you could just iterate through all your anchor elements and run this function with the desired phrase.

If you have a bunch of these with the .txt class you can just do something like:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
  changeTarget(elems[i], "THE BEST SITE");
}
```

Comment: `innerText` isn't standard, use `textContent` instead. And better `elem.target = phrase;` than `setAttributte`.

Comment: Awery, how do I call this? <a changeTarget(this,'Text')> ?

Comment: I cannot make any changed to "a tag" because it is in codebehind file (aspx.cs file) and I don't have code with me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. If you're going to be able to run a script on the page, and there is HTML, you can query and change the DOM elements. I'm not familiar with aspx.cs files so I'm not sure what factors are holding you back, but this is the way you'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i)
    if(els[i].textContent == "THE BEST SITE")
        els[i].target = 'something';
```